# How to find the correct font ttf for the FPDI/FPDF Japanese Character in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fonts, cjk, fpdi

I am using FPDI/FPDF Library for my Laravel PDF export. I am having problem with Japanese Font it turns into like this:

```
ãƒ’ãƒ«ãƒ‡ãƒ¢ã‚¢ã•Ÿã•¾ãƒ—ãƒ©ãƒ¼ã‚¶ãƒ»ãƒ“ãƒ¬ãƒƒã‚¸â…¢
```

it should be like this:

```
派遣先責任者署名䠄代理者も含む䠅
```

I tried a lot of fonts and still same character is showing. I know how to install new font in FPDI/FPDF library. the only problem is the right font. Or how to set up correct encoding or font in FPDI FPDF library.

These are the fonts I tried
`ipagothic`, `msminchu`, `mona`, `droidsans`, and `gkai00mp`, none of these will work.

Comment: Looks like you are having a character encoding issue, not font. Font issue I think would appear as `?` or `#`.

Comment: how to set up the encoding for japanese then?

Comment: Probably utf8 what charset are you using?